# Getting the text and not value with Delphi Ole Automation of Excel

Tags: excel, delphi, automation, delphi-7, excel-2010

I'm looking to extract the text of each cell in a given range for an Excel spreadsheet using Ole Automation in Delphi 7.

Just now I have a function that (assuming the workbook is already open) selects a range from a worksheet and populates a Variant array using the .Value2 function

```
function GetExcelRange(const AWorkbookIndex: integer; const AWorksheetIndex: integer; const firstCol, lastCol, firstRow, lastRow: integer): Variant;
var
 AWorkbook, ARange: OleVariant;
begin
 Result := Unassigned;
 if not VarIsEmpty(ExcelApp) then
 begin
  if ExcelApp.Workbooks.Count >= AWorkbookIndex then
  begin
   AWorkbook := ExcelApp.Workbooks[AWorkbookIndex];
   try
    if AWorkbook.Worksheets.Count >= AWorksheetIndex then
    begin;
     ARange := AWorkbook.WorkSheets[AWorksheetIndex].Range[AWorkbook.WorkSheets[AWorksheetIndex].Cells[firstRow, firstCol],
                                   AWorkbook.WorkSheets[AWorksheetIndex].Cells[lastRow, lastCol]];
     Result := ARange.Value2;
    end;
   finally
    AWorkbook := Unassigned;
    ARange := Unassigned;
   end;
  end;
 end;
end;
```

What I would expect is I could change the line to be `Result := ARange.Text` but it returns a null object.

I would prefer to not iterate over each cell whilst the Ole object is active and stick the whole range's text into an array like I'm doing above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I infer from your question that you want to read the text contents of the cell as are presented to the user in Excel. I don't think you can perform the operation on an entire range. The way I have done that in the past is like this. Note that I'm using early bound COM.

```
function GetCellVariant(const Sheet: ExcelWorksheet; const Row, Col: Integer): OleVariant;

  function ErrorText(const Cell: ExcelRange; hr: HRESULT): string;
  const
    ErrorBase=HRESULT($800A0000);
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    Result := Cell.Text;
    for i := 1 to Length(Result) do begin
      if Result[i]<>'#' then begin
        exit;
      end;
    end;
    if hr=ErrorBase or xlErrDiv0 then begin
      Result := '#DIV/0!';
    end else if hr=ErrorBase or xlErrNA then begin
      Result := '#N/A';
    end else if hr=ErrorBase or xlErrName then begin
      Result := '#NAME?';
    end else if hr=ErrorBase or xlErrNull then begin
      Result := '#NULL!';
    end else if hr=ErrorBase or xlErrNum then begin
      Result := '#NUM!';
    end else if hr=ErrorBase or xlErrRef then begin
      Result := '#REF!';
    end else if hr=ErrorBase or xlErrValue then begin
      Result := '#VALUE!';
    end else begin
      Result := 'an error';
    end;
  end;

var
  Cell: ExcelRange;
  hr: HRESULT;
begin
  Cell := GetCellAsRange(Sheet, Row, Col);//effectively this is Sheet.Range
  if VarIsError(Cell.Value, hr) then begin
    raise ECellValueError.CreateFmt(
      'Cell %s contains %s.',
      [R1C1toA1(Row,Col), ErrorText(Cell, hr)]
    );
  end;
  Result := Cell.Value;
end;

function GetCellString(const Sheet: ExcelWorksheet; const Row, Col: Integer): string;
var
  Value: Variant;
  Cell: ExcelRange;
begin
  Value := GetCellVariant(Sheet, Row, Col);
  if VarIsNumeric(Value) then begin
    Cell := GetCellAsRange(Sheet, Row, Col);
    Result := Sheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Cell.Value, Cell.NumberFormatLocal);
  end else begin
    Result := ConvertToString(Value);//this converts a Variant to string
  end;
end;
```

In fact this code came out of the very first question I ever asked here on Stack Overflow: [How do I read the formatted textual representation of a cell in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164044/how-do-i-read-the-formatted-textual-representation-of-a-cell-in-excel)

Comment: +1, but reading your last sentence the question actually is a duplicate? :-D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
var
WS:tExcelWorksheet;
icolor:integer;
dato:olevariant;
```

...

```
icolor:=WS.cells.item[1,1].Interior.Color;
dato:=WS.Cells.item[2, 4].value;
dato:=WS.Cells.item[2, 4].textformat;
```

You can find many, many examples here:

http://delphimagic.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/funciones-excel.html
http://delphimagic.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/trabajar-con-graficos-en-excel-con.html